# Issue with serializing abstract class

Tags: java, android, serialization

I'm trying to serialize an abstract and pass it onto an activity but I'm getting the error `java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.example.MainActivity$1)`.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String AUTO_EXTRA = "AUTO_EXTRA";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        RelativeLayout l = new RelativeLayout(this);
        l.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        new Setup.auto(this) {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(String message) {

            }
        };
    }
}
```

Setup.java

```
public static class Setup {
    public static abstract class auto implements FailedAuto, Serializable {
        public auto(Activity activity) {
            auto a = (auto) this;
            Intent i = new Intent(activity, AutoSetup.class);
            i.putExtra(AUTO_EXTRA, a); // Error happens here.
            activity.startActivity(i);
        }
    }

    private class AutoSetup extends Activity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            ((auto) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(AUTO_EXTRA)).onFailure("Message");
        }

    }

    private interface FailedAuto {
        void onFailure(String message);
    }
}
```

I have two classes, MainActivity and Setup, when I run the code I get the error on line `i.putExtra(AUTO_EXTRA, a);`. I found that Serializing MainActivity solves this problem but I don't want MainActivity to be `Serializable` and I don't understand as to why it thinks I'm serializing MainActivity. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous inner class contains the reference of the class in which it is included. In this case, the class `MainActivity` which is not serializable. So you got the error. So you need to make the subclass of your base class in a separate class file.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by subclass of my base class, I'm not quite clear on what you mean.

Comment: I meant your abstract class. Make another new class like this: 

    public class AutoImpl extends auto{
        //implementation
    }